# Netbeans - Dreamweaver Integration

Tags: web-applications, web, dreamweaver, netbeans-6.9

Greetings,

I am coding a JavaEE project. But I am having a hard time deploying my pages from Dreamweaver CS4 to Netbeans 6.9.1.
Is there a way to integrate Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 to Netbeans 6.9.1 so that either way around the pages will synchronize upon update between the two IDEs.

Thanks,
Cyril H.

Comment: My best tip would be just to drop Dreamweaver from your workflow completely, you will not regret it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a project in Netbeans. and copy your html files in the particular folder. Now goto dreamweaver and create a dreamweaver site in the folder where you have copied the html files. (It will be somewhere in your netbeans project folder). No matter where you edit since the location of the file is you you should not have any problem of synchronization.

I do something similar in eclipse.

Comment: Aside from this, is there a way to synchronize the current project of Netbeans with the current managed site of Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0):

The "real" answer here is as Vija has indicated, you must set up your Dreamweaver site such that it's local root folder is at the same location as the Netbeans project is set up as.

However, if your files are not currently sync'd, then you'll need to do something similar to the following:

In Dreamweaver CS4:
Site -> Manage Sites. Select your site, click Edit.
Make sure you are on the Advanced tab, select the "Remote Info" category. Then in the Access list, select Local/Network (assuming that the files are one the same system, or share the same network drive), otherwise, select the appropriate Access option.
Select the Remote folder (or specify other remote info as necessary)

Make sure to check, "Maintain synchronization information". I don't generally recommend it, but you may also want to check the "Automatically upload files to server on save". This auto upload on save will move your files to the Netbeans project every time you save a document within your site.

The site definition dialog has changed for Dreamweaver CS5, so the same options ca be found at:
Site -> Manage Sites. Select your site, click Edit.
Select "Servers" on the left.
Click the Add button (+) and provide a name for your "sever", and in the "Connect with" list, select "Local/Network".
Select the Server folder (or specify other remote info as necessary)
Switch to the Advanced tab. Check the "Maintain synchronization information" and/or "Automatically upload files to server on save" boxes as appropriate.

Once you have enabled synchronization for your site, select the appropriate site in the Files panel, then right click on the root for for your site, and select "Synchronize...".

For the options within the Synchronize dialog, see the help contents (this link convers CS5, but the info should be pretty much the same for CS4 and CS5):
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7ea4a.html

Once you have your files synchronized in one location or the other (local or "remote"), then you should really change the site definition in Dreamweaver to point to the Netbeans project, or switch Netbeans to define the project at the Dreamweaver site location. You are asking for trouble if you do not move to having the same set of files that you're working with.